# Why my Spring Boot application don't start actuator even after config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-actuator

My Spring Boot application use actuator to do health check. I use this configuration:

```
management.server.port = 9093
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = health
```

The k8s cluster try http get to host:9093/acutator/health to do the health check. It works well when run on local machine and I try to use the same Dockerfile to build a docker container to my own local machine is also ok. But when I push it to the k8s cluster in prod env, the health check keep failed because connect to 9093/actuator/health failed.

I observed the log on prod env and found that Netty server don't listen 9093 port. I can only see

```
o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8080
```

But on my local machine, I can see the log that Netty started on port 9093.

```
o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 9093
```

The question is, in what situation, Spring Boot will not start actuator? Seems it's related to k8s env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed might be related to you k8s setup.

Spring Application doesn't make any assumptions whether it runs within the k8s environment or without any containerization at all.

You can try to execute a call via WGET to the actuator from within the pod itself (assuming WGET/CURL are available there) and make sure that the endpoint is accessible.

If its indeed accessible, check out [Actuator Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.kubernetes-probes) that explains in detail how to set the k8s probe.

Also check the typos, in the question you use a word `acutator` twice, whereas it probably should be an `actuator` ;)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I confuse with this thing, Netty Server don't start on 9093. I use python SimpleHTTPServer to take 9093 port first then the Spring Boot still succesfully start on 9093. What env setting could make Spring Boot give up start Actuator but without any error message ?

Comment: Spring boot wise, `server.port` is a variable that points on the port to start the server on (default 8080), `management.server.port` is for actuator (management). It possible to override these values with environment variables, parameters to run the program, etc. Spring boot has many ways to provide configurations. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#:~:text=Spring%20Boot%20lets%20you%20externalize,line%20arguments%20to%20externalize%20configuration.

Comment: Problem solved, it read config from external but also application.yml, but I write xxx=xxx in application.yml because all the settings in application.yml are not loaded, but the weird thing is Spring doesn't report any error even in the log (info level).